# Inputting list of data

Tags: led

Sorry if this question has been asked but I can't seem to find an answer because I don't really know if I'm phrasing the question correctly.

I'm trying to control a grid of LED to light up in a specific sequence that is based on a long list of data (and loops over time). Is there any way to bring in the data automatically? (vs individually coding the digitalWrites and delays) I think I found a reference project a few days ago but I lost it.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer in detail, but in broad terms, probably yes.

Comment: Google `for` loops and arrays - that should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is vague so I have made some assumptions, I hope they are right.

The first is I have assumed you are relatively in experienced at programming, I hope that's right otherwise the rest of this may seem patronising.

You have a number of LEDs arranged in a grid (lets say 3x3 to make life easy).
You are asking is there an alternative to doing this:

```
// Step 1
digitalWrite (LED1, HIGH);
digitalWrite (LED4, HIGH);
digitalWrite (LED8, HIGH);
delay (100);
digitalWrite (LED1, LOW);
digitalWrite (LED4, LOW);
digitalWrite (LED8, LOW);
// Step 2
// And so on...
```

Yes there are, and there are many, I think this is probably going to be the easiest to start with.

**Coding the data in a 2D array.**

An array is a fixed length list of values of the same type.  One obvious use for an array is to hold the pin numbers for you LEDS, rather than having LED0 through to LED8.

```
#define LED0 2
#define LED1 3
// and so on
```

Alternative array version

```
//  Define the number of elements in the array
#define MaxLEDs 9
// Define the array
const int LEDPins[MaxLEDs] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

I have declared the array as `const` because the values in it aren't going to change.  The array is going to hold integers (because that's what `digitalWrite()` takes as a pin number) and there are 9 of them.  Rather than use the literal 9 I have defined a constant because I know that value is going to be used elsewhere in the code and this means it is easier to change the number of LEDs.

So how does this help you?  Well you can define an array of 'steps' and each step has a list of which LEDs are switched on.  As your code loops through the steps it turns the specified LEDs, waits and then turns them off.  The simplest way to encode the data would be for each 'step' element to be an array of Boolean values (each true value indicates a light that should be on during this step).  I have chosen Booleans because it will use the least amount of space, which is always an issue on an Arduino.  Depending on the number of steps and LEDs you may need to look at alternative storage methods, like just the LEDs that are on, but it will do for now.

```
const bool theSteps[MaxSteps][MaxLEDs] =
{
    {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}
  , {false, true , false, false, true , false, true , false, false}
  , {false, false, true , true , false, false, false, true , false}
  , {true , false, false, false, false, true , true , false, false}
};
```

You still have to code the data within the program, but its much smaller

```
//  Define the number of elements in the array
#define MaxLEDs 9
// Define the array
const int LEDPins[MaxLEDs] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

const bool theSteps[MaxSteps][MaxLEDs] =
{
    { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false }
    ,{ false, true , false, false, true , false, true , false, false }
    ,{ false, false, true , true , false, false, false, true , false }
    ,{ true , false, false, false, false, true , true , false, false }
};

#define StepDelay 100

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
    for (int onOff = 0; onOff < 2; ++onOff) // Turns the LED on and off
    {
        for (int step = 0; step < MaxSteps; ++step)
        {
            for (int led = 0; led < MaxLEDs; ++led)
            {
                if (theSteps[step][led])  // If the LED should be on
                {
                    digitalWrite(LEDPins[led], (onOff < 1) ? HIGH : LOW);
                }
            }
        }
        if (onOff < 1)
            {
                  delay(StepDelay);
            }
    }
}
```

I'm afraid I haven't tested any of this code (it might not even compile) but the theory is right and it should give you a shove in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about arrays because I haven't coded in a while... I'm still fiddling with the code because I'm actually trying to do 3 separate arrays of data that shifts/scrolls across one direction (step++ at the end of each loop and shifting the array for each set of data) but I think I've almost got it.